# Using Cordova plugins dependent on same custom framework

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have two different Cordova plugins, that use the same custom framework. So there is a copy of this framework in each plugin.

Hence the framework is copied and added twice in the project from different locations.
This results in a conflict while compiling and linking.

Can I solve this problem by adding some flags in one of the plugin's plugin.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on how the plugins are done (you didn't specify wich plugins nor wich framework you are talking about).

It is possible that both the plugins you are using are copying the framework to the same folder and the framework is actually only once in your app when it's built. (check plugin.xml)

If not you still can fork the plugins or install them from a local copy to make them use the framework from a common location or have the framework in a third plugin and define it as a dependency for the other plugins.

Comment: The plugins and the framework are created by me. I have created two plugins for different purposes. So if I share these two plugins with others and if they use both the plugins, their project will complain about referring the same framework twice. Note that the plugins are different and each has a copy of the framework. Plus, I don't want them to do anything more than `cordova plugin add`. Any suggestions in this case?

Comment: Either you could make a third plugin containing only the src of the framework and add this third plugin as a dependency in the two other ones, or if in you two plugins you put the framework in the same location so in the final app it will only be present once (only side effect would be that uninstalling one of the two plugins would delete the framework and then the other would have to be reinstalled to continue to work properly)